# HTML5, <section> inside unordered list

Tags: html, html-lists, article

Can I use `<section>` tag inside unordered list?

I know, that `<section>` represent a generic section of document. Usually we find heading inside.

So... I have list of products. Usually about 20 per page. Each element have:

- heading,
- short description (max 255 chars),
- thumbnail, some details, button.

So each list item is something like section, `"is a thematic grouping of content, typically with a heading"`.

Of course I don't use, `<section>` to styling purpose.

I think, `<section>` also could be here a wrapper for a list, and each element of list `<article>`.

What is your opinion?

Answer (score 6):

Using a `<section>` tag inside an `<li>` tag validates (you can try this using the “Text Field” option on http://html5.validator.nu/), and the spec doesn’t seem to suggest you shouldn’t use it in this way (see http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/the-section-element.html#the-section-element), so that seems fine to me.

The `<article>` tag is meant for [“self-contained compositions”](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/the-article-element.html#the-article-element). I’ve never been entirely clear what that means outside of several blog posts being listed on a single page, but I think product summaries sound like a decent fit for that too. So your second idea of a `<section>` containing the entire list, and an `<article>` for each product, probably sounds best.

Comment: In HTML5 validator we can even put whole page in `<header>` tag, but it's not a point. Yes, product summary fit... Hmm... I will consider this...

Comment: I see your point re validation, it’s just a good first thing to check. Don’t worry too much about the semantic considerations — they’re necessarily fuzzy.

Answer (score 0):

**A List of DOs…**

DO use section for each individual section of a tab switcher or content slider (if an unordered list isn’t needed)
DO use section to divide a lengthy “terms and conditions” (or similar) page into numbered sections
DO nest section elements if necessary (as you might do with the “terms and conditions” page)

**A List of DON’Ts…**

DON’T use section to divide content from the header and footer; use div instead (see the doctor)
DON’T use section to wrap a tab switcher for DOM manipulation or styling
DON’T use section for sidebar or other tangentially-related content boxes; use aside instead
DON’T use section just to add a border or drop shadow around something; use div instead
DON’T use section for the wrapper when implementing faux columns; again, use div instead
DON’T use section to nest elements when trying to avoid IE6′s float double-margin bug (or a similar layout-related issue); again, use div
DON’T use section to hold an individual author bio on a blog post or news article; use aside instead

Stolen from [When to Use the HTML5 “section” Element](http://www.impressivewebs.com/html5-section/)

Comment: Not sure I’d put much stock into that article. It seems to think that when the spec says “ A Web site’s home page could be split into sections for an introduction, news items...” that it’s saying each news item should be a `<section>` instead of an `<article>`, when it seems to actually mean that a `<section>` would contain all the news items, each of which would presumably be marked up as an `<article>`.